# Do something if body has a class of "ie." Do something else if body does not have a class of "ie."

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I think I wrote this wrong because it's not working as I intended.

I want it to work like this:

If `body` does not have the `ie` class, and if `body.single #project-wrapper` has the `activated` class, it should add the `grayscale` class and change the `opacity`.

If `body` has the `ie` class, and if `body.single #project-wrapper` has the `activated` class, it should just change the `opacity`.

How can I rewrite the code below to reflect what I wrote above?

```
if (!$(body).hasClass('ie')) {
    if ( $('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') ) {
        $('article.project').addClass('grayscale').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
}

if ($(body).hasClass('ie')) {
    if ( $('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated') ) {
        $('article.project').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use element selector for body. There is no variable called `body` so you should be having an error like `ReferenceError: body is not defined` in your console

```
if ($('body').hasClass('ie')) {
    if ($('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) {
        $('article.project').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
} else {
    if ($('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) {
        $('article.project').addClass('grayscale').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
}
```

---

Since the condition `$('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')` is common you can do something like

```
if ($('body.single #project-wrapper').hasClass('activated')) {
    if ($('body').hasClass('ie')) {
        $('article.project').css('opacity', '0.4');
    } else {
        $('article.project').addClass('grayscale').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I just realized this. I will grant you the check when I can.